# Can't find the author field in python's library - feedparser

Tags: python, feedparser, author

I'm writing a program to parse an rss feed and print a couple of attributes such as title, date etc.
I succeeded extracting most of the data except the author field.
I tried various methods and searched here : https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/feedparser/latest/feedparser.pdf

but still after parsing i don't see (in my Debugger) the field author and of course when i tried printing it the program throws an exception.

So if anyone knows how to get this field it will be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the following page of feedparser documentation about authors that may be of use to you: [This link!](https://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/reference-feed-author_detail.html#reference-feed-author-detail)

In short, you can do `feed.author_detail.name` to get the author's name, `feed.author_detail.href` to get a link to their webpage, and `feed.author_detail.email` to get their email.

If this helped you, click the check to the left of this answer!

Comment: Hi, saw that one and tried pretty much every possible option there and didn't work.
thx

Comment: @RavivTrichter Did you try using `feed.author`?

Comment: @arman311 yeah so i tried all the above and it's still not working. I don't see any attribute called author and every time i try a different variation as explained above an exception is thrown :
AttributeError: object has no attribute 'author'